# Why no maas-cli for 12.04 LTS?

Tags: maas

The documentation for MAAS describes how to do all sorts of things with maas-cli, but maas-cli doesn't seem to be available for 12.04.2 LTS. Is there an LTS release of Ubuntu where I can use MAAS in the way it's described in the documentation?

Comment: MAAS is available on 12.04 server, but you have to choose it at install time - have you tried this?

Comment: The documentation says that I can install MAAS with "apt-get install maas" which is what I've done. I tried "apt-get install-maas-cli" just in case there was a suitable package, but that didn't work either.

Comment: you'll also need to install the cluster controller and/or region controller packages as appropriate (they're called `maas-cluster-controller` and `maas-region-controller`)

Answer (score 0):

Add maas stable repo from https://launchpad.net/~maas-maintainers, and install maas.

$ sudo maas shell